# Wix: Install Windows Service with user specified service name

Tags: windows, service, installation, wix

I have an installer project to install a Windows Service. This installer contains a UI Dialog to allow user to specify the Service Name. This Service Name is stored to a public property. Installer creates the service with specified name successfully, but when I try uninstall it, installer tries to stop and delete services with default Service Name property (not specified by user).

My service install code looks like this:

```
...
<Property Id="SERVICE_NAME" Value="Default_Service_Name" />
...
<Component Id="C.service.exe" Guid="...">
        <File Id="service.exe" Name="$(var.service.TargetFileName)" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes"
              Source="$(var.service.TargetPath)" />
        <ServiceInstall Id="MyServiceInstall" DisplayName="[SERVICE_NAME]" Account="[SERVICE_ACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICE_PASSWORD]"
                        Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes">
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceStart" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" Start="install" Wait="no" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceStop" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" Stop="both" Wait="yes" />
        <ServiceControl Id="MyServiceRemove" Name="[SERVICE_NAME]" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
...
```

Maybe I need some CA to update SerciceControl table after user will specify Service Name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to persist any user-provided data that's needed to uninstall, for example by saving it to the registry. See [The WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern).